# How do I make R a part of Cygwin's path

Tags: r

I have both R and Cygwin installed on my 32-bit XP machine.  In trying to execute the following command in Cygwin,

MAKEFLAGS="-j 24" R CMD INSTALL boom.tar

I get the Cygwin error "-bash R: command not found"

I need to make R part of my path for Cygwin.

How do I do this?

Comment: You do know that Cygwin is not a supported development environment for R, don't you?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't matter.  Once I get R into my Cygwin path I'll know if the software I'm trying to run will even work in Windows or not since it was built for Unix...

Comment: Good luck. This posting to rhelp might be of use: http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help+build+R+for+cygwin#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20build%20R%20for%20cygwin+page:1+mid:hh5gxdyhlrkesjeo+state:results

Comment: Thank you again!  I've switched from Cygwin to MinGW...but the bottom line is that I should probably be doing this in Linux, not Windows...

Answer (score 1):

Modify your .bashrc to include it on your path

`export PATH=$PATH:"/cygdrive/C/Path/To/R"`

Comment: In adding this to Cygwin's .bashrc, it generated the following error "-bash: $'\r': command not found"   SO!  BondedDust was right...Cygwin doesn't support R...   Thank you both!

Comment: I set the PATH by going into Windows 7's environment variables. The PATH was correct on Cygwin, but I got "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". So close yet so far...